# Disable Shopware administration notification worker

Tags: shopware6

Right now the administration notification worker sends a request every 5s. This is quite annoying when debugging with a debugger like xdebug, because the requests pile up.
Is there a way (maybe through configuration) to disable the fetch of notifications?

Comment: It would be interesting to know why Shopware did not use [Server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events) to solve that. Maybe someone has an idea?

Answer (score 5):

Not a permanent solution but you can overwrite the function that fetches the notifications by executing the following in the dev-tools console of your browser:

```js
Shopware.Service('notificationsService').fetchNotifications = () => Promise.resolve({ notifications: [] });
```

You could also automate that by using an browser extension or writing a small plugin that has a minimal admin component just containing that line.